# What is the default execution policy on different Windows versions?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server

What is the default execution policy on different Windows versions? I understand that there is an execution policy named **Default** and it is different on Windows client and server operating systems. However, does a fresh Windows installation actually have the "Default" execution policy set?

Comment: According to [About_Execution_Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7), the default execution policy is based on the OS type. On a Windows client, that is Restricted. On a Windows server, that is RemoteSigned. On non-Windows systems, the default is Unrestricted.

Answer (score 1):

I just booted into a fresh install of Windows 10 Ver. 20H2 and ran `Get-ExecutionPolicy` in Powershell and it returned Restricted